# Responsive hamburger menu doesn't disappear after click

Tags: javascript, menu, dropdown

I found this codepen. How to make hide dropdown menu after click on menu section? It's provided for mobiles, so you have to make your window smaller to see hamburger menu. When I click on some sections it moves me to this section on page but menu still is on screen and covers page.

[Codepen][1]

[1]: https://codepen.io/Gcamara14/pen/XBKNbz

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question?

Comment: that codepen works as it should as far as I can see - so the code in that codepen should answer any question you haven't asked

Comment: Look, if you click on hamburger icon menu section appears. If I click on ‚home’ for example it moves me to this section on website but dropdown menu is still on screen. I want to disappear this menu after click on menu section. Don’t know you understood me for sure.

Comment: I found this site where menu works like I want. / https://www.kimilewis.com/

Comment: Add an onclick event to every link in the menu and uncheck "nav" checkbox.

Comment: Triby, still it doesn't works.. or maybe I am doing something wrong.